# Session Parameter does not pass until reloaded

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, webdatagrid

I have a sessions parameter that gets the cell data from webgridview1 and uses it to pass information into webgridview2, 
The session is being updated properly but the second webgridview is not being populated until I manually click the reload button

```
Public Sub WebDataGrid1_CellSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SelectedCellEventArgs) Handles WebDataGrid1.CellSelectionChanged
    Dim pressName = e.CurrentSelectedCells(0).Text
    Session("PressName") = pressName
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

I tried an updatepanel, but that is not either working.
Response.Redirect brings up an empty page with the gridviews gone
how can i either reload my page, or have the session pass into the webdatagrid again?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
                <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" Width="400px" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataPressNames">
                    <Columns>
                        <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="RecordNumber" Hidden="True" 
                            Key="RecordNumber">
                            <Header Text="RecordNumber" />
                        </ig:BoundDataField>
                        <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="PressName" Key="PressName">
                            <Header Text="PressName" />
                        </ig:BoundDataField>
                        <ig:BoundCheckBoxField DataFieldName="PressActive" Key="PressActive" >
                            <Header Text="PressActive" />
                        </ig:BoundCheckBoxField>
                    </Columns>
                    <Behaviors>
                        <ig:Selection>
                            <AutoPostBackFlags CellSelectionChanged="True" />
                        </ig:Selection>
                    </Behaviors>
                </ig:WebDataGrid>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataPressNames" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [RecordNumber], [PressName], [PressActive] FROM [PressInfoNew] ORDER BY [PressName]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>


                       <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                           DataSourceID="SqlDataPressInfo" Width="400px">
                           <Columns>
                               <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="PressName" Key="PressName">
                                   <Header Text="PressName" />
                               </ig:BoundDataField>
                               <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="MinWidth" Key="MinWidth">
                                   <Header Text="MinWidth" />
                               </ig:BoundDataField>
                               <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="MinHeight" Key="MinHeight">
                                   <Header Text="MinHeight" />
                               </ig:BoundDataField>
                               <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="MaxWidth" Key="MaxWidth">
                                   <Header Text="MaxWidth" />
                               </ig:BoundDataField>
                               <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="MaxHeight" Key="MaxHeight">
                                   <Header Text="MaxHeight" />
                               </ig:BoundDataField>
                           </Columns>
                       </ig:WebDataGrid>
                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataPressInfo" runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" 
                           SelectCommand="SELECT [PressName], [MinWidth], [MinHeight], [MaxWidth], [MaxHeight] FROM [PressInfoNew] WHERE ([PressName] = @PressName) ORDER BY [PressName]">
                           <SelectParameters>
                               <asp:SessionParameter Name="PressName" SessionField="PressName" Type="String" />
                           </SelectParameters>
                       </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: show your .aspx page

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a DataBind for the second Grid View in the code you have shown. Try this

```
Public Sub WebDataGrid1_CellSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SelectedCellEventArgs) Handles WebDataGrid1.CellSelectionChanged
    Dim pressName = e.CurrentSelectedCells(0).Text
    Session("PressName") = pressName
    WebDataGrid2.DataBind()
End Sub
```